# Displaying the number of valid results for a range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table with a creation date and a expiry date. I currently have a sql command to get the number of valid items for a given date.

```
select 
    count(id) ,CONVERT(date, getdate()) 
 from 
    table 
 where 
    createDate < getdate() and expDate > getdate()
```

This returns the count and current date.

Is it possible to wrote a sql query that will return the result for a range of dates, say I if wanted to plot the number of valid items over a range of 15 days?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #datelist (ValidDateCheck date, ValidResults int)

declare @startdate date = '1/1/2015'
declare @enddate date = '2/1/2015'
declare @interval int = 1 --Use 1 if you want every day between your dates, use 2 if you want every other day, etc.

declare @datecounter date = @startdate
declare @count int

while @datecounter <= @enddate
begin
set @count = 
    (select count(*) 
    from Table 
    where CrtDt <= @datecounter and ExpDt > @datecounter)
insert into #datelist values (@datecounter, @count)
set @datecounter = dateadd(dd, @interval, @datecounter)
end

select * from #datelist order by 1
```

It loops through all the dates in your range, counting valid results for each one.

Answer (score 2):

Check this,

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';

SELECT  
        DATEADD(d, x.number, @StartDate) AS MonthName1
        ,
        x.number
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```

The above query give the list of dates between 2 dates.

As per your table and question, check this also.

```
declare @table table(id int,frdt datetime, todt datetime)

insert into @table values (1,GETDATE()-20, GETDATE()-19)
,(2,GETDATE()-9, GETDATE()-8)
,(3,GETDATE()+20, GETDATE()+18)
,(4,GETDATE(), GETDATE()-1)
,(5,GETDATE()-20, GETDATE())
,(6,GETDATE()-10, GETDATE()+10 )

select * from @table

declare @frdt datetime = null , @todt datetime = getdate()-10

select @frdt, @todt,* from @table
where
 (@frdt is null or @frdt between frdt and todt)
and
 (@todt is null or @todt between frdt and todt)

 select @frdt = GETDATE()-15 , @todt = GETDATE()

 select @frdt, @todt,* from @table
where
 (@frdt is null or @frdt between frdt and todt)
 and 
 (@todt is null or @todt between frdt and todt)
```